# Adding a native C file as library to Android project

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, native-code, android-library

I am to create an Android application that performs the arithmetic functions such as addition, subtraction, multiplication, division.

I know it's a simple application but to make it a bit complex, I have written it in C, it is called "ArithmeticOperations.c".

Now that I would like to include this .c file as a library to my Android project.

I tried:

1. using Android NDK, it worked but I have to provide the code to the user
2. I created an .so file using Android NDK separately and included in the **libs/armeabi** folder of the test application; and it showed **Unsatisfiedlinkerror** Exception
3. using android NDK, I built a simple android project and converted to jar so that it can be imported to other application and it did not work too.

How can I provide this .c file as a library to an Android project?

**first.c**

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
return x+y;
}

int sub(int x, int y)
{
return x-y;
}

int mul(int x, int y)
{
return x*y;
}

int div(int x, int y)
{
    return x/y;
}

**second.c**

#include "first.h"
#include <jni.h>

jint
Java_bri_ndk_sample_ArithmeticOperations_add( JNIEnv*  env,
                                  jobject  this,
                                  jint     x,
                                  jint     y )
{
return add(x, y);
}

jint
Java_bri_ndk_sample_ArithmeticOperations_sub( JNIEnv*  env,
                                  jobject  this,
                                  jint     x,
                                  jint     y )
{
return sub(x, y);
}


jint
Java_bri_ndk_sample_ArithmeticOperations_mul( JNIEnv*  env,
                                  jobject  this,
                                  jint     x,
                                  jint     y )
{
return mul(x, y);
}


jint
Java_bri_ndk_sample_ArithmeticOperations_div( JNIEnv*  env,
                                  jobject  this,
                                  jint     x,
                                  jint     y )
{
 return div(x, y);
}
```

**first.h**

```
extern int add(int  x, int  y);
extern int mul(int  x, int  y);
extern int sub(int  x, int  y);
extern int div(int  x, int  y);
```

**Android Activity**

```
package bri.sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SampleTestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
static{
     try{
            System.loadLibrary("twolib-second");
     }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    final EditText xVal = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText yVal = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final TextView result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    //final Arithmetic al = new Arithmetic();

    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int x = Integer.parseInt(xVal.getText().toString());
            int y = Integer.parseInt(yVal.getText().toString());
            Integer z = add(x, y);
            result.setText(z.toString());
        }
    });

    Button sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    sub.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int x = Integer.parseInt(xVal.getText().toString());
            int y = Integer.parseInt(yVal.getText().toString());
            Integer z = sub(x, y);
            result.setText(z.toString());
        }
    });

    Button mul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    mul.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int x = Integer.parseInt(xVal.getText().toString());
            int y = Integer.parseInt(yVal.getText().toString());
            Integer z = mul(x, y);
            result.setText(z.toString());
        }
    });

    Button div = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    div.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int x = Integer.parseInt(xVal.getText().toString());
            int y = Integer.parseInt(yVal.getText().toString());
            Integer z = div(x, y);
            result.setText(z.toString());
        }
    });

}

public native int add(int  x, int  y);
public native int sub(int  x, int  y);
public native int mul(int  x, int  y);
public native int div(int  x, int  y);
}
```

Now that I want this C file as a library to Android

This can also be looked into as

1. adding .so file to Android project
2. adding a jar file that contains a .so file to an Android project

Comment: Have you tried looking at samples/hello-jni example that comes with Android NDK?

Comment: @MārtiņšMožeiko, +1 for mentioning samples, they are really helpful...

Comment: @MārtiņšMožeiko i have tried the mentioned sample. it worked. Thing is i would like to distribute my library and not my source. NDk requires source to be distributed.

Comment: i have added more code to the question kindly refer

Comment: To anyone else attempting to answer this question, when the OP refers to "user", the OP does not mean "user". The OP means "developer".

Answer (score 2):

> i created an .so file using android NDK separately and included in the libs/armeabi folder of the test application; and it showed Unsatisfiedlinkerror Exception

Did you load the library using system.loadLibrary()? You should do it inside the "static" part of your class, see for example [this](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/09/android-invoke-jni-based-methods-bridging-cc-and-java/).

Answer (score 0):

Putting shared library (.so file) under libs/armeabi folder and calling correctly System.loadLibrary(...) should work fine. No need to distribute source.

Verify that .so file is really in .apk file (it's a zip file), and verify that you are calling loadLibrary with correct name.

Comment: how did u build the .so file?? is it through android NDK. i have no good idea about jni. it would be better if u suggest a good sample application.

Comment: hello-jni example under samples directory in NDK is very good starting point. Take a look at it. Also read NDK documentation under docs directory.